# Postgresql: select rows by OR condition - including going through json array

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql, where-clause

I have a table created by following query:

```
create table data
(
    id integer not null unique,
    owner text,
    users jsonb not null
);
```

The table looks like this:

```
+----+-------+---------------------------------------------+
| id | owner |                    users                    |
+----+-------+---------------------------------------------+
|  1 | alice | []                                          |
|  2 | bob   | [{"accountId": "alice", "role": "manager"}] |
|  3 | john  | [{"accounId": "bob", "role": "guest"}]      |
+----+-------+---------------------------------------------+
```

I need to get rows 1 and 2 on behalf of Alice.

Getting owner-based rows works perfect:

```
SELECT *
FROM data
WHERE owner = 'alice'
```

Getting jsonb-based rows is a little trickier though managable:

```
SELECT *
FROM data, jsonb_array_elements(users) x
WHERE (x ->> 'accountId') = 'alice'
```

But getting them together gets me just the jsonb-based ones:

```
SELECT *
FROM data, jsonb_array_elements(users) x
WHERE owner = 'alice' OR (x ->> 'accountId') = 'alice'
```

How do I get the selection that looks like following?

```
+----+-------+---------------------------------------------+
| id | owner |                    users                    |
+----+-------+---------------------------------------------+
|  1 | alice | []                                          |
|  2 | bob   | [{"accountId": "alice", "role": "manager"}] |
+----+-------+---------------------------------------------+
```

Even better if I can get a selection that looks like this

```
+----+----------+
| id |   role   |
+----+----------+
|  1 | owner    |
|  2 | manager  |
+----+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the empty json array, which evicts the corresponding row from the result set when `cross join`ed with `jsonb_array_elements()`. Instead, you can make a `left join lateral`:

```
select d.*
from data d
left join lateral jsonb_array_elements(d.users) as x(js) on 1 = 1
where 'alice' in (d.owner, x.js ->> 'accountId')
```

Note that, if your array always contains 0 or 1 element, tyou don't need the lateral join - your query  would be simpler phrased as:

```
select d.*
from data d
where 'alice' in (d.owner, d.data -> 0 ->> 'accountId')
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=e9191bdd5ec6cbd88242d9e7c8639e2a)** - both queries return:

```
id | owner | users                                      
-: | :---- | :------------------------------------------
 1 | alice | []                                         
 2 | bob   | [{"role": "manager", "accountId": "alice"}]
```